# REPLACE INTO on MySQL not working (table structure issue?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table with two columns: `id` and `member_id`

I have a script set to update that table doing something like this...

`REPLACE INTO AT_infinite_math_visibility VALUES(97, 16);`

It doesn't seem to work unless I specify one of the columns as the "primary key".  However, the data entered into this table would likely end up being like this...

First Row: 97, 16

Second Row: 97, 22

Third Row: 104, 16

Fourth Row: 104, 74

So, how should I set up this table to...

1.) Not have duplicate entries upon new updates.

2.) Insert a new record if it won't be a duplicate.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? REPLACE INTO is essentially an `INSERT` that gets translated into an `UPDATE` if the insert would cause a unique key violation. If you don't have any unique keys, then no violation could ever occur, and you'd just be running an overly verbose `INSERT` query.

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL? In that case you should be using UPDATE table SET x = yy (WHERE some condition). Good luck.

Comment: @MarcB: `REPLACE INTO` translates into `DELETE` followed by `INSERT` on key violation (unlike `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` which behaves like you said).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace works by first deleting anything colliding with your unique keys, then inserting whatever you requested.

Without unique keys, like primary key, it will just be an expensive insert.

If you don't won't any duplicates on both columns just define them both as the primary key

```
alter table AT_infinite_math_visibility add primary key (id, member_id);
```

Comment: Setting both as primary keys was the answer.  Thanks!